# How to deselect bottom sheet when clicking on bottom_bar_with_sheet library child items version 2.1.0 flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm implementing some custom buttons using this package:

```
bottom_bar_with_sheet 2.1.0
```

I added the following code snippet below, but I am not able to remove the default selection of the button when clicking on the child buttons I have been trying in many ways but not being able to progress.

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomBarWithSheet(
        // selectedIndex: selectedPosition > 3 ? 4 : _selectedIndex,
        selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
        controller: _bottomBarController,

onSelectItem: (index) {
          setState(() {
             _selectedIndex = selectedPosition > 3 ? -1 : index;
          });
        },
```

and in the action button of the child I did like this:

```
setState(() {
          selectedPosition = posicao;
          _selectedIndex = posicao; 
        });
```

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: I solved it like this with a suggestion that I was made _bottomBarController.selectItem(psosicao);

Answer (score 0):

One of my problems was solved how can I add navigation where each button would lead to a parent route of a view, and this view will have other screen possibilities, where it will have routes too, what better way to do that in this plugin
using good practice like mobx?

this is the code in a single file, but I would like to separate the components.

```
import 'package:bottom_bar_with_sheet/bottom_bar_with_sheet.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _bottomBarController = BottomBarWithSheetController(initialIndex: -1);
  int selectedPosition = 4;
  int _selectedIndex = -1;


  @override
  void initState() {
    _bottomBarController.itemsStream.listen((i) {
      if( i < 4 )
      {
        setState(() {
          selectedPosition = -1;
          _selectedIndex = i;
        });
      }

      switch(i)
      {
      // case "HOME" :  FutureBuilder: Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> Home())); break;
        case 0: print("Acesso rápido 0");break;
        case 1: print("Acesso rápido 1");break;
        case 2: print("Acesso rápido 2");break;
        case 3: print("Acesso rápido 3");break;
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          "Criar navegacao aqui",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 20,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomBarWithSheet(
        selectedIndex:_selectedIndex,
        controller: _bottomBarController,
        bottomBarTheme: BottomBarTheme(
          mainButtonPosition: MainButtonPosition.middle, // posicao do botao de 'mais -> (+)'
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(25)),
          ),
          itemIconColor: Colors.grey,
          itemTextStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.grey,
            fontSize: 10.0,
          ),
          selectedItemTextStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.blue,
            fontSize: 10.0,
          ),
        ),
        onSelectItem: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _selectedIndex = index;
          });
        },
        sheetChild: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:10,bottom:6),
          child:Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Divider(
                height: 10,
                thickness: 2,
                color: Colors.blue,
                indent: 0,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: GridView.count(
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), //kill scrollable
                  // shrinkWrap: true,
                  crossAxisCount: 4,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    _createBottomBarSheetChild(context, 'Home', Icons.api_sharp, _routeMenu, 4),
                    _createBottomBarSheetChild(context, 'Produto', Icons.apartment, _routeMenu, 5),
                    _createBottomBarSheetChild(context, 'Cliente', Icons.person, _routeMenu, 6),
                    _createBottomBarSheetChild(context, 'Proposta', Icons.account_balance_wallet_outlined, _routeMenu, 7),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: GridView.count(
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), //kill scrollable
                  // shrinkWrap: true,
                  crossAxisCount: 4,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    _createBottomBarSheetChild(context, 'Reservas', Icons.add_location_rounded, _routeMenu, 8),
                    _createBottomBarSheetChild(context, 'Unidade', Icons.workspaces_filled, _routeMenu, 9),
                    _createBottomBarSheetChild(context, 'Contratos', Icons.work, _routeMenu, 10),
                    _createBottomBarSheetChild(context, 'Tarefas', Icons.calendar_today, _routeMenu, 11),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        items: [
          BottomBarWithSheetItem(label: "Notas",icon: Icons.notes),
          BottomBarWithSheetItem(label: "Perfil",icon: Icons.account_circle),
          BottomBarWithSheetItem(label: "Configurações",icon: Icons.settings),
          BottomBarWithSheetItem(label: "Alertas",icon: Icons.add_alert),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget _createBottomBarSheetChild(BuildContext context, String name, IconData icon, Function action, posicao)
  {
    return GestureDetector(
      child: Card(
        elevation: 0,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
            left: 3.0,
            top: 25,
            right: 3.0
        ),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(
              icon,
              size: 26,
              color: selectedPosition == posicao ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 4, bottom: 6, ),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    name,
                    // textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: selectedPosition == posicao ?
                      Colors.blue :
                      Colors.grey,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Divider(
                    height: 16,
                    thickness: 2,
                    color: selectedPosition == posicao ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                    indent: 30,
                    endIndent:30
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),

      onTap: () {
        // Navigator.pop(context);
        setState(() {
          selectedPosition = posicao;
          _bottomBarController.selectItem(posicao);

        });

        Navigator.of(context);
        action(context, name, posicao);
      },
    );
  }

  _routeMenu(context, rota, posicao)
  {
    print("rota ${rota.toUpperCase()}");

    switch(rota.toUpperCase())
    {
      case "HOME" :""; posicao = 5;break;
      case "PRODUTO":"";posicao = 6;break;
      case "CLIENTE": "";posicao = 7; break;
      case "PROPOSTA": "";posicao = 8; break;
      case "RESERVA": "";posicao = 9;  break;
      case "UNIDADE": "";posicao = 10; break;
      case "NOVIDADE": "";posicao = 11; break;
      case "TAREFAS": "";posicao = 12; break;
    }
  }
}
```